# Compute Lebesgue measure of set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal representations don't contain the number 7

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure, decimal-expansion

Consider measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu) = (\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R), \lambda)$.

Let $V^C \subseteq S$ denote the set of all numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal representations don't contain the number 7.

1. Prove that $V^C \in \Sigma$.
2. Compute $\lambda(V^C)$.

---

What I tried:

1. I think we have

$$V = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n$$

where $v_n \in V_n$ can be written $v_n = 0.s_1s_2...$ where $s_1 \ne 7, ..., s_{n-1} \ne 7, s_n = 7$

$$V_n = \bigcup_{s_1, ..., s_{n-1} \ne 7} [0.s_1...s_{n-1}7, 0.s_1...s_{n-1}8)$$

$V$ is a finite union of pairwise disjoint $9^{n-1}$ intervals and hence is a Borel set, which is Lebesgue measurable.

$V$ is a countable union of  pairwise disjoint Borel sets and hence is a Borel set, which is Lebesgue measurable.

Thus, $V^C$ is Lebesgue measurable.

2.

$$\lambda(V) = \lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} V_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(V_n)$$

$$\lambda(V_n) = \lambda \left(\bigcup_{s_1, ..., s_{n-1} \ne 7} [0.s_1...s_{n-1}7, 0.s_1...s_{n-1}8)\right)$$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^{9^{n-1}} \lambda ([0.s_1...s_{n-1}7, 0.s_1...s_{n-1}8))$$

$$= \sum_{i=1}^{9^{n-1}} \frac{1}{10^n} = \frac{1}{10^n} \sum_{i=1}^{9^{n-1}} (1) = \frac{1}{10^n} (9^{n-1} - 1 + 1) = \frac{9^{n-1}}{10^n}$$

$$\to \lambda(V) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda(V_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{9^{n-1}}{10^n} = 1$$

$$\therefore, \lambda(V^C) = 0$$

Comment: Looks fine to me, except perhaps the transition from line 2 to 3 in part 2. That might be the cardinality of the set, but its not what the thing that you're summing over really is.

Comment: @user24142 Thanks ^-^ Expand on anything, and post as answer?

Comment: Your answer is fine, but I'd keep the same subscript on the sum on line 3 as you have on the union on line 2.

Comment: @user24142 What do you mean? (Post as answer?)

Comment: Please don't place a bounty as means of preventing people from voting to close your question.

Comment: seriously? my question was 1st @AsafKaragila eh

Comment: It's not about being first. This is not a YouTube comment section. You can find some good discussions and arguments on meta for why older questions are sometimes closed as duplicate of newer ones. Placing a bounty to prevent closure, however, is a flagrant abuse of the bounty system for which there are no redeeming arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line $$= \sum_{i=1}^{9^{n-1}} \lambda ([0.s_1...s_{n-1}7, 0.s_1...s_{n-1}8))$$ doesn't immeadiately make sense. Your summands don't depend on i in any way. Use the subscript you had before, ie $$= \sum_{s_1,\ldots, s_{n-1} \ne 7} \lambda ([0.s_1...s_{n-1}7, 0.s_1...s_{n-1}8)).$$ I should say that what you have is correct, but it doesn't look like it follows, and the reader will have to think to realise why it follows. You don't want that, you want the progression of ideas to be obvious.

I'd also be sure to add some explanatory sentences, just so that what you are doing is clear. Less logical symbols, more words.

Comment: Of course it depends on I. You just didn't see the $i^0$ :P Anyway thanks for the tips, user24142 ^-^