# Is this set borel measurable?

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I am having trouble on proving this.

Let $\xi $ be the set of all real numbers containing a five in their decimal representation. Why is it borel measurable?

I hope someone can help me out here. Thanks

Comment: May be you could same kind of reasoning as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154298/measure-of-set-of-numbers-in-0-1-with-their-decimal-expansions-not-containin)

Comment: Yea i´ve seen this but we arent that far for now. We just reached the definition of a borel set and that all elements in the borel set are borel measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Prove that

$$ A_n = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \ : \  \lfloor 10\cdot (10^{n-1} x -\lfloor 10^{n-1} x \rfloor) \rfloor = 5 \} = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} \ : \ x \text{ has a } 5 \text{ at the nth place in the decimal expansion}  \}$$

is Borel measurable. The countable union of Borel measurable sets is Borel measurable.

**Added:** To prove that $A_n$ is Borel. Prove that the function $$f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ f_n(x)= \lfloor 10\cdot (10^{n-1} x -\lfloor 10^{n-1} x \rfloor) \rfloor$$

is a Borel function (which you can either check by hand or use the fact that it is piecewise continuous). To see that $f_n$ gives the $n$th place in the decimal expansion, we consider $x= b_m \dots b_0. a_1 a_2 \dots$, then we get
$$ 10^{n-1} x = b_m \dots b_0 a_1 \dots a_{n-1}. a_n a_{n+1} \dots $$
and thus
$$ \lfloor 10^{n-1} x \rfloor = b_m \dots b_0 a_1 \dots a_{n-1}. \overline{0},$$
which implies
$$ 10^{n-1} x - \lfloor 10^{n-1} x \rfloor = 0.a_n a_{n+1} \dots $$
and therefore
$$ \lfloor 10\left(10^{n-1} x - \lfloor 10^{n-1} x \rfloor \right) \rfloor
= \lfloor a_n. a_{n+1} \dots \rfloor = a_n. $$

**Easier solution:** Prove that $$A_n \cup \{ x \text{ has a } 6 \text{ at the } n\text{th place in the decimal expansion and only zeros afterwards.} \}$$ is closed (if every element of a sequence has a 5 at the nth place of their decimal expansion, then the limit will have a 5 at the nth place of their decimal expansion or (as pointed out by @Erdbeer0815 it converges to the number having a 6 at the nth place of their decimal expansion and only zeros afterwards) and deduce that it is a Borel measurable set.

Comment: thank you alot got it

Comment: What about the sequence 5.9, 5.99 , 5.999 ... the sequence is in $A_{n}$ but its limit is 6?

Comment: @Erdbeer0815 Thanks for your remark.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven why this function $f_n$ gives us the nth digit in the decimal expansion?

Comment: @CloudJR It doesn't. I will fix it today. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @CloudJR I corrected it and gave a proof. I hope it is fine now.