# Is $\dfrac{1}{2}$ in the set of real numbers containing the digit 5?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $F = \{x\in[0,1]: x \text{ does not contain the digit 5}\}$

At first it's obvious that $1/2=0.5\in F$, but the problem arises when you write $1/2=0.499...\notin F$, which leads to a contradiction.

How do you measure such a set $F$ with this ambiguity? (This can be done as seen in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154298/measure-of-set-of-numbers-in-0-1-with-their-decimal-expansions-not-containin) question). Is it because the set of numbers that can be represented in such a non-unique way has measure $0$?

Comment: The set of rationals has Lebesgue measure zero.

Comment: For any non-zero real number with a terminating decimal representation, there is always exactly one more non-terminating representation that is equivalent (in that it represents the same real number). The problem is usually taken care of definitionally, i.e. consider only non-terminating representations of every real, which means that every member will have only one representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. Since, as you observed, decimal expansions are not unique, the definition of $F$ could be improved.  Consider $$F_1 = \{x \in [0, 1] : \text{no decimal expansion of $x$ contains a 5}\} \\ F_2 = \{x \in [0, 1]: \text{$x$ has a decimal expansion with no 5s}\}$$
Clearly $F_1 \subset F_2$ and the containment is proper because $\tfrac{1}{2} \in F_2$ but $\tfrac{1}{2} \not\in F_1$.  Since the only numbers for which the repeating 9s ambiguity exists are finite decimals, we have $F_2 \setminus F_1 \subset \mathbb{Q}$.  Since the measure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is zero, $F_1$ and $F_2$ have the same measure.

Comment: Your last sentence is kind of superfluous, given that $F_1$ and $F_2$ both have measure $0$.

Comment: @TonyK Thank you. I left it because the issue at hand is the matter of resolving an ambiguous definition.

Comment: Ummm $-$ OK$\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

That is an invalid definition. The set of real numbers is not in $1-1$ correspondence with the set of decimal expansions, as you are obviously aware. So the predicate "$x$ does not contain the digit $5$" is not well-defined.