# Proof that $A$ has $0$ measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $A$ be a set of all real numbers from  interval $[0,1]$ which decimal representation is
>   $$ 0, c_1 c_2 c_3 c_4 ...  $$ (may be infinite)
>   and there is no $j$ such that $c_j = 0 \wedge c_{j+1} = 0$. Proof that $A$ has $0$ measure.

Until now, I was able to do this type of task using this method: [Measure of Set of numbers in $[0,1]$ with their decimal expansions not containing digit $5$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154298/measure-of-set-of-numbers-in-0-1-with-their-decimal-expansions-not-containin/2154341#2154341) .

However, this time this method is not enough and I do not know how I can deal with it

Comment: In number system of base $100$, the set of numbers without any $0$ digits is a subset of this.

Comment: @Berci Ok, but what if the number looks like i.e. $0.1001 = 1/2 + 1/16$ (I mean, the first $0$ from pair occurs on even index) - then in base $100$ it looks like $0.(90)$ so how can I detect that this is subset of numbers with $00$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_k:=\{x\in[0,1]\mid x_k\neq 0 \text{ or } x_{k+1}\neq 0\}$ where $x_k$ is the $k$'th digit in decimal expantion.

Let $C_k=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{k}B_i$

Obviously $A=\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}C_i$

Since $m(C_1)\leq m([0,1])<\infty$, and $m(C_{k+1})\leq m(C_k)\cdot0.99$, we get: $m(C_k)\leq0.99^k$

This implies  $m(A)\leq \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}m(C_k)\leq\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}0.99^k=0$

Comment: can we just say that $A = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$?

Comment: @newuser458 Yes!