# Finding the measure of a set with some specific property.

Tags: measure-theory

For each $x \in [0,1]$ we consider its decimal expansion $x = $0.d1d2 . . . where we do not
allow the expressions that terminate in nines. Let $S$ denote the set of all those elements
whose decimal expansion does not contain the digit $3$. Is S Borel measurable? If yes,
what is its measure?

Here is the link of similar question.

[What is the measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansions do not contain $5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154298/what-is-the-measure-of-the-set-of-numbers-in-0-1-whose-decimal-expansions-do)
So, the measure of the set of numbers in $[0,1]$ whose decimal expansion does not contain $3$ is zero. Denote this set by $A$
So, the measure of the given set $S$ should be zero, because it is a subset of the set $A$, so its measure is either zero or less than zero.
So, it is exactly $0$

Can I argue like this.
If not, how can I find the measure of the given set $S$ $?$