# Morphism into Dedekind scheme is an open immersion?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I was working on exercise 4.1.14 from Liu's 'Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves' book:

> Let $X$ be an integral scheme of dimension 1, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a separated birational morphism of finite type from $X$ to a Dedekind scheme. Show that $f$ is an open immersion.

I had some problems at a certain point in the proof, so I decided to take a look at an example that 'shows' these problems:
$$X=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}[3/2]$$
$$Y=\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$$
and $f$ is simply the morphism induced by the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}[3/2]$. First of all $X$ is an integral scheme of dimension 1 and $Y$ is a Dedekind scheme. $f$ is obviously separated and of finite type and it is birational as it induces the identity on the function fields (which are just $\mathbb{Q}$). However, $f$ is not an open immersion for the following reason: Since $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[3/2]$ there is some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $\mathbb{Z}[3/2]$ with $2\in\mathfrak{m}$. Then $$\mathfrak{m}\cap\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}=:\mathfrak{p}$$
The morphism $$f^\#_{\mathfrak{m}}:\mathcal{O}_{Y,\mathfrak{p}}\to\mathcal{O}_{X,\mathfrak{m}}$$
is not surjective as $3/2$ is not in $\mathbb{Z}_{2\mathbb{Z}}=\mathcal{O}_{Y,\mathfrak{p}}$. Therefore $f$ is not an open immersion.
What concerns me about this is that Liu writes in that exercise that this statement is a special case of "Zariski's Main Theorem", so there is probably some mistake somewhere in this 'counterexample'. Can someone tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: thanks for voting to leave open https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592620/compute-lebesgue-measure-of-set-of-all-real-numbers-in-0-1-whose-decimal-rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[3/2]$ with inverse $\frac{3}{2}-1$.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I overlooked that ;D