# Find the value of :- $2010 - \sum_{k=1}^{2010}\bigg\lceil\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor\bigg\rceil $

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Find the value of :- $$2010 - \sum_{k=1}^{2010}\bigg\lceil\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor\bigg\rceil $$

**What I Tried**: Quite stuck at the problem. I need to find some short cut to evaluate the summation but not been able to do so till now. 
I know that the factors of $2010$ are $1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30,67,134,201,335,402,670,1005,2010$ . So for all these values in $k$ , the sum of the terms will be $0$ . So we can actually cancel these terms out from the list of $\{1,2,3, ... ,2010\}$ .

The problem is, what about the other numbers? For example, $\frac{2010}{4} = 402.5$ , which can be actually considered $402$ like $5$, but for $\frac{2010}{9} = 223.33$ , it will be considered $223$ , which is actually one number not like $10$ though.

So can anyone help me?

Comment: That’s basically no. Of factors of 2010,

Comment: Either the no. Will be 1 or 0 when u apply that operation , so value for factors will be zero and value for non factors is 1

Comment: Wait, do you mean that if $k$ is not a factor of $2010$ , then the value of that term will be $1$ ?

Comment: Oh nvm I got it, I missed out that  we have a ceiling function, I got it anyways.

Comment: We have
$$ \frac{2010}{k} - \lfloor \frac{2010}{k} \rfloor \in [0,1) $$
and thus
$$\lceil \frac{2010}{k} - \lfloor \frac{2010}{k} \rfloor
 \rceil \in \{ 0, 1\}.$$
Hence, if $k$ is not a factor of $2010$ the expression is $1$.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore not really, the 1st function is floor and the other one is ceiling.

Comment: $\frac{2010}k - \left\lfloor\frac{2010}k\right\rfloor$ is the decimal part $\left\{\frac{2010}k\right\}$, so taking the ceiling of the decimal part becomes $1$ if $k$ is not a factor.

Comment: @Anonymous i did not see that oops

Comment: @peterwhy I have already got the solution and the understanding, it's basically the number of factors $2010$ has , because whenever k does not divide 2010 the value will be 1.

Comment: thanks for voting to leave open https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592620/compute-lebesgue-measure-of-set-of-all-real-numbers-in-0-1-whose-decimal-rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $k$ is not a divisor of 2010, then
$\bigg\lceil\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor\bigg\rceil=1$
and if $k$ is a divisor, $\bigg\lceil\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor\bigg\rceil=0$
(That's actually because $\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor=${$\frac{2010}{k}$}  ({n} is the fractional part of n) and {$\frac{2010}{k}$} is between $0,1$ and is equal to $0$ whenever $\frac{2010}{k}$ is an integer and is equal to $1$ otherwise.
So actually $\sum_{k=1}^{2010}\bigg\lceil\frac{2010}{k} - \bigg\lfloor \frac{2010}{k}\bigg \rfloor\bigg\rceil=2010-$(number of positive divisors of 2010)
So the final value you're asking for is equal to the number of positive divisors of 2010 which is 16.